# What does the phrase "boot down" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me understand the meaning of the phrase "boot down" in the following text from the description of the game "Bomb Chicken":

*It can double as a barrier to keep enemies away, too. But these aren’t smart bombs – your payload is as deadly to you as anyone else.
When the way you get around is also the biggest danger you face, exploring becomes thrillingly tense and tricky.
But as long as you’re careful, you’ll never cry fowl – and there’s little more satisfying than mastering the ‘lay and punt’ technique, where you **boot a freshly-fabricated bomb down** a tunnel to clear it out, or at a distant switch to open a door.*

I know that the lexical meaning of the word "boot" is "to kick"/ However, I am confused by the word "down"here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *Down* is just a preposition, indicating the direction in which the bomb was booted (kicked). In this case, down a tunnel. You *knock **on** a door*, *walk **down** a hallway*, and *climb **up** some stairs*.

Comment: @JasonBassford My query is solved. Should I delete the question because you have given this information as a comment and not as an answer?

I am asking this to ensure that I am not breaking norms here.

Comment: You can if you wish, or you can wait for somebody to give a proper answer with more detail than what I put into my comment. Were you confused by the addition of *freshly-fabricated* that distracted from the more direct *boot a bomb down a tunnel*, or the use of *up* instead of *down* (for instance)? Or something else?